# Travis CI starts a job over `deploy` branch automatically, and fails

Tags: travis-ci, github-pages

I set up a deployment job for a Hugo Blog on GitHub Pages, the code itself is stored in `dev` branch while the static files that are the rendered blog are stored in `master` branch.

Therefore I created a YAML `.travis.yml` file that renders everything into `public/` and deploys it to `master`. The relevant part of the `.travis.yml` looks like this:

```
branches:
    only:
        - dev
    except:
        - master

deploy:
    github_token: $GITHUB_TOKEN
    provider: pages
    target_branch: master
    skip_cleanup: true
    local_dir: public
    on:
        branch: dev
```

This works perfect. Whenever I push code to `dev` the script is ran and the static website is being rendered and generated to `public/`, but for some reason, this also creates an automatic build job, created and started by `Deployment Bot (from Travis CI)`.

I don't have a `.travis.yml` file in `master` branch so Travis obviously complaints about this, stating:

```
Could not find .travis.yml, using standard configuration.
```

and later on fails after executing `rake`:

```
$ rake
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The command "rake" exited with 1.
```

I understand why this job fails. The problem is that this job should have never run in first place. There is no reason to run any CI job on the static files, which are the result of the original intended CI job.

How can I make Travis stop building this job automatically after deploy? Travis does not ignore builds on master branch although it is listed under `branches: except` in the YAML file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Travis CI [must have a `.travis.yml` file in each active branch of your project](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Building-Specific-Branches).

A branch "safelist" takes precedence over a "blocklist" too. Try changing your `branches:` section to:

```
branches:
  only:
  - dev
```

... and putting a `.travis.yml` in your master with that in it too.